# Can a matrix with missing values be an isomorphism, if so how do you find the inverse?

Tags: linear-algebra, inverse

I have the following matrix for T: R3->R3 with respect to the standard basis:

\begin{array}{ccc}
1 & 1 & 0 \\
 & -1 & 1 \\
 &  & 1 \end{array}

and was wondering if such a matrix could be an isomorphism, i.e. whether it has an inverse or not (is this the right logic?).

So I'm looking for a $T^{-1}$ such that $TT^{-1}=I_{output space, i.e. R3}$ or 1 1 1?

I was thinking that such an inverse transformation could be of the form

\begin{array}{ccc}
b_{11} & b_{12} & b_{13} \\
b_{21} & b_{22} &  \\
b_{31} & &  \end{array}

whereupon I could solve for the $b$ variables after doing $TT^{-1}$, but I have more variables than equations, so this seems wrong.

Tips appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can very easily fill in values such that the matrix has an inverse, for example,
$$\pmatrix{1&1&0\cr \color{red}{0}&-1&1\cr \color{red}{0}&\color{red}{0}&1\cr}
  \quad\hbox{or}\quad
  \pmatrix{1&1&0\cr \color{red}{1}&-1&1\cr \color{red}{1}&\color{red}{1}&1\cr}\ .$$

Comment: Do missing values mean that they can filled in? Surely if so, then unassigned variables would be inserted instead...

Comment: Addendum: what would the dimension of such a matrix be? Because we know that (T^-1)T = identity matrix of the input vector space right

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood your question.  If you are asking, "is the (incomplete) matrix **always** an isomorphism", then the answer is no, because I have given an example where it isn't.

Comment: Indeed, the question is not whether it's always an isomorphism, but if it ever could be... and incomplete doesn't mean empty values can be filled with 0's

Comment: See new answer.

Comment: Thanks, And what if empty spaces can't be filled in whatsoever ?

Comment: In that case it is sometimes an isomorphism as in my answer, and sometimes not as in my previous answer.